# Layout issue between Relative Layout and Coordinator Layout

Tags: android, material-design, floating-action-button, android-coordinatorlayout

Can someone help me in understanding layout issue between the Relative Layout and Coordinator Layout.Initially i used Floating Action button in Relative Layout.Below is the code.

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/primary_color"></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/searchfab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
            app:fabSize="normal">

        </android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Output:

[image]

Inorder to work with Snackbar i used Coordinator layout in the same code. But i got the Floating action bar in different position.

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/primary_color"></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/searchfab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
            app:fabSize="normal">

        </android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

output:

[image]

Anyhow i solved the issue by replacing android:layout_alignParentRight and android:layout_alignParentBottom with android:layoutGravity="right|bottom".

The question is why android:layout_alignParentRight and android:layout_alignParentBottom is not working for coordinator Layout although its height and width kept as match_parent.

Appreciate your answer.Thank  you.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `android:gravity="bottom|right"`, `layout_alignxxxx` only works for children under `RelativeLayout`

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/searchfab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
        app:fabSize="normal">
```